# What is purpose of these paragraph?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, self-learning

The following paragraphs are from my study notes on probability theory. It is a section within the independence discussion. But to me, they seem to appear here out of blue. I do not understand what exactly the question we are trying to answer here is. In particular, in the first paragragh, it starts with $\{0, 1\}$ and then basically forgets this case in latter discussion. As for those theorems, it does not make sense to me why we want to do them. In other words, what is the logic or intuition behind all of the discussion, please? Could anyone clarify the point, please? Thank you!

[image: 1]

**Update:** I think the theorem referred above can be thought of as the justification for why we can generate iid random numbers from a given distribution. The solution provided by this theorem is that for certain probability space we can be assured to generate iid uniform random numbers. Once this is done, we can use the so called inverse quantile function to have iid random numbers from any given distribution (only in principle since it is not alway easy or even possible to invert the CDF). I think this is why we need this theorem in the first place. Right?

Comment: it states that for any choice of probabilities $P(E)=p$ and $P(\bar E)=1-p$ one can indeed find a random variable in a measureble probability space which fullfils this distribution

Comment: @NikosM. Then what does this have to do with the $(0, 1)$ case, please? The discussion starts with $\{0, 1\}$. But then the entire discussion that follows is on the continuous case $(0, 1)$. How are these two related, please?

Comment: I fail to see how the (quickly accepted) answer answers the question at all since the passage in the textbook is concerned with *independent sequences* of random variables having *any distributions whatsoever*, not with some unique Bernoulli random variable--but if the OP is happy with this...

Comment: @Did Please refer to my update for this question. Any comments are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I read your update, it reinforces my previous comment.

Comment: @Did Could you provide some detail about your comments, please? I think my update provides some intuition on why we need the theorem. Do you agree, please? Or what do you have in mind, please? Thank you!

Comment: Here are some details about my previous comment explaining what I have in mind: "I fail to see how the (quickly accepted) answer answers the question at all since the passage in the textbook is concerned with independent sequences of random variables having any distributions whatsoever, not with some unique Bernoulli random variable--but if the OP is happy with this..."

Comment: @Did, hmm just saw the update, indeed i answered rather quickly,  i can ammend my answer, but if you have a better one, you can post it and probably remove mine (i'll see)

Answer (score 1):

Adding comments as an answer:

The theorem states:

That for any choice of probabilities $P(E)=p$ and $P(\bar{E})=1−p$ one can indeed find a random variable $X$ in a measureble probability space which fullfils this distribution.

$p \in (0,1)$ is a necessary condition, $p$ **is** a probability and if either $1$ or $0$ it is trivial and not random. The set $\{0,1\}$ is the set that the (proved) random variable $X$ takes values in. It is **not** related to the probability $p$. In fact one can use random variable $Y=(b−a)X+a$ which takes values in $\{a,b\}$